# replace words in a google doc with words from google sheets - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I followed instructions and triple checked this code and can't find any discrepancies but I'm still getting this error. **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Please help me

````
  var title = e.values[0];
  var surname = e.values[1]; 
  var fullNames = e.values[2];
  var ID = e.values[3];
  var taxNumber = e.values[4];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1tX6l8ZAHs9Lv9Np1fdOZXPbsFqMcx8ggPv5So8WZ-cM");

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17F678vzKcE7AaVqef0k-f96uHCOJeotv");

  var copy = file.makeCopy(surname + ',' + fullNames, folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{FullNames}}", fullNames);
  body.replaceText("{{Surname}}", surname);
  body.replaceText("{{ID}}", ID);
  body.replaceText("{{IncomeTaxNumber}}", taxNumber);

  doc.saveAndClose();

}```
````

Comment: Which line is error? First?

Comment: I tried to look now and couldn't find any indication of line. It's my first script and I'm not sure about something... If my sheet has multiple tabs, how will my script know which tab to use?

Comment: Or does it only run on the first Form responses tab?

Comment: To answer those questions, please provide your full code and if you use any installable trigger - also mention this. Your error message should be something like `Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 19, file "Code")` - this is how you know what the line is.

Comment: The full error reads **TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
    at autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(Code:3:21)**

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the whole code though as it's very long. This is line 3 though: `var timestamp = e.values[0];`

Comment: Without full code we can only guess "e" is an object variable that should be passed to trigger function, but you invoke it incorrectly for some reason, that's why object is empty.

Comment: It needs to complete a G.doc every time a form is submitted but I need to complete 2 types of docs for different data entries so I tried to make simplified tabs on the spreadsheet that extract the info needed but it gave me the above error. So I changed the values to conform to the 1st Form responses and then I submitted a test form response, then I get an error saying `Script function not found:` (I changed the function name) but 2 minutes later I get another error saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
    at autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(Code:3:21)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFormSubmit(e) {
  var title=e.values[0];//This is a timestamp
  var surname=e.values[1]; 
  var fullNames=e.values[2];
  var ID=e.values[3];
  var taxNumber=e.values[4];
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById("1tX6l8ZAHs9Lv9Np1fdOZXPbsFqMcx8ggPv5So8WZ-cM");
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("17F678vzKcE7AaVqef0k-f96uHCOJeotv");
  if(surname && fullNames && ID && taxNumber && folder && file) {
    var copy=file.makeCopy(surname + ',' + fullNames, folder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    var body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText("{{FullNames}}", fullNames);
    body.replaceText("{{Surname}}", surname);
    body.replaceText("{{ID}}", ID);
    body.replaceText("{{IncomeTaxNumber}}", taxNumber);
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}

function createFormSubmitTrigger() {
  if(!isTrigger('myFormSubmit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFormSubmit').forForm('formId').onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I still get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
    at myFormSubmit(Code:3:21)** or **TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")** I copied your code exactly except for the values that has a list of 242 lines (it's a big spreadsheet). I also entered the Form ID at 'formID'. Line 3 is the Timestamp

Comment: I also tried to use the Form responses ID instead of the Form's ID and received the same error

Comment: Can I make copies of the sheet and form and share it?

Comment: Perhaps your using the onFormSubmit for a form as oppose to the one for a Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

If

`var timestamp = e.values[0];`

throws you the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined`

**it means that you are trying to run the script manually by pressing the "Play" button**

This is something you cannot do it in a function that runs on trigger and uses [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

- In your case `e.values` are an event object - values that are passed to your spreadsheet at the moment of form submission, they can only be retrieved at the moment the trigger is fired.
- If you run your function manually - there will be no event values passed to your spreadsheet at this very moment and thus `values` will be `undefined` and your script `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined`

**Workaround**

If you want to test either the rest of your code is working as intended - test it with hardcoded dummy values.

- You can use the [ternary conditional-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that checks if the defined variable (e.values) exists, and if it doesn't - assigns default value.

  Sample:

  `timestamp = e ? e.values[0] : "5/28/2020 11:32:48";`
- This line means that if the event object `e` exists (when the function is fired by the trigger), `timestamp` will be `e.values[0]`.
- If `e` does not exist (because you are testing the function manually), the hardcoded value `5/28/2020 11:32:48` will be assigned to `timestamp`.
- Please implement this to all of your `e.values` to avoid the error `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it right by removing all the other tabs in the spreadsheet. Thanks for the help though!